# Programmatically make colour slightly darker version of fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to highlight the bounday line of a density, using ggplot2, with the same colours as I use for fill, only slightly darker. Here is a small example:

```
ggplot(chickwts, aes(x = weight)) +
  geom_density(bins = 25, aes(fill = feed, colour = feed)) +
  facet_wrap(~feed) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Georgia", size = 12, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

Which gives me the following plot:

[image]

What I would ideally like is to show the boundary line of the density in these same colours, but slightly darker. I could do this manually with `scale_colour_ manual()`, but I *really* don't want to do that. Is there a way to do this with ggplot2, perhaps with `alpha()`, or something like that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Jfortin1/72ef064469d1703c6b30

Comment: @Masoud thanks, that looks useful for some other things I wanted to do.

Comment: You're welcome. `alpha` sets transparency btw; not darker or lighter.

Comment: Yeah< i was just thinking about that. R.B.'s answer gets me what I need right now, but that gist is more useful long-term. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you need is to add the alpha parameter :

```
geom_density(bins = 25, aes(fill = feed, colour = feed), alpha=0.3)
```

wish that this could help

Answer (score 7):

The default discrete scale is `hcl` so you could darken its `l` value:

```
last_plot() + scale_colour_hue(l = 40)
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!